# How to unmerge cells in a spreadsheet using apache POI java library

Tags: java, apache-poi

We can use `sheet.addMergedRegion(rowFrom,rowTo,colFrom,colTo);` for adding merged cells in the sheet But I already have a sheet with merged cells in it and I want to unmerge these cells.

Is there any way to unmerge cells of a sheet without creating new sheet using Apache POI ?

Comment: Won't [Sheet.removeMergedRegion](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeMergedRegion%28int%29) do you?

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not able to unmerge using sheet.removeMergedRegion.!!

Comment: Why not? What error do you get? What goes wrong? What isn't working?

Comment: Its working now! There is some formatting problem with my excel sheet. Thank you very much.!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The method you want is [Sheet.removeMergedRegion(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeMergedRegion%28int%29)

That takes the index of the region, which you got when you added it. Otherwise, you can use [getNumMergedRegions()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getNumMergedRegions%28%29) and [getMergedRegion(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMergedRegion%28int%29) to iterate over the regions to find the index of the one you want to remove

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that internally the number of existing regions is checked after every region method. E.g. after removing Region 1 everything is new calculated like size is previousSize-1 and sheet.getNumMergedRegions() is also one less. So for me I added all regions to a list and deleted them from the sheet. I took always id 0 as the id is recalculated everytime.

```
for(int i = 0; i<numOfRegion;i++)
        {
            regions.add(sheet.getMergedRegion(0));
            sheet.removeMergedRegion(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the following code did not remove all the merged regions at once:

```
logger.info("Number of merged regions = " + sheet.getNumMergedRegions());
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
    logger.info("Removing merged region " + (i + 1));
    sheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
}
logger.info("\nNumber of merged regions = " + sheet.getNumMergedRegions());
```

In the console I see this:

```
Number of merged regions = 7
Removing merged region 1
Removing merged region 2
Removing merged region 3
Removing merged region 4

Number of merged regions = 3
```

**Fix:**

```
while (sheet.getNumMergedRegions() > 0) {
    logger.info("Number of merged regions = " + sheet.getNumMergedRegions());
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        logger.info("Removing merged region " + (i + 1));
        sheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i had a document with some cells merged already.
So when i needed to merge some region, i had to unmerge any merged cells inside that range. The guy who said that the index recalculates saved me.

```
private CellRangeAddress mergeRange(Range range, XSSFSheet sheet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getMergedRegions().size(); i++) {
        CellRangeAddress r = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        int fRow = r.getFirstRow();
        int lRow = r.getLastRow();
        int fCol = r.getFirstColumn();
        int lCol = r.getLastColumn();

        if (fRow >= range.getFirstRow() && fRow <= range.getLastRow() &&
            lRow >= range.getFirstRow() && lRow <= range.getLastRow() &&
            fCol >= range.getFirstCol() && fCol <= range.getLastCol() &&
            lCol >= range.getFirstCol() && lCol <= range.getLastCol()) {
            sheet.removeMergedRegion(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    return sheet.getMergedRegion(sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(range.getFirstRow(), range.getLastRow(), range.getFirstCol(), range.getLastCol())));
}
```