# How to swap up columns in a xlsx file in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am working in a xlsx file , where i have to just append the values in the lower row to the upper row.Also i have to skip that row from the output file.First i am giving the excel file screen

[image]

I have to append the values below the row Name6 i.e in the header there will be Name1,Name2,Name3....... Name6admin|Name6loc, Name7.

For now the since the cells are merged cell poi is giving the output as Part of a merged cell after Name6.i.e Name6|part of a merged cell that way .I want to modify that as i mentioned.
Now my code is working like I will have All the rows starting from Name1 to Name7 and all the below values they hold.And the thing is i am generating the output in a text file which can not contain the row below Name1,Name2,...etc.But i also have to append values from that . I am givinf my code

```
 @Override
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    final int startCell=0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {

//skipping the rows which i can not contains in the output 
if(currentRow.getRowNum()==0 || currentRow.getRowNum()==1|| currentRow.getRowNum()==2|| currentRow.getRowNum()==3|| currentRow.getRowNum()==4|| currentRow.getRowNum()==5|| currentRow.getRowNum()==6|| currentRow.getRowNum()==7|| currentRow.getRowNum()==9|| currentRow.getRowNum()==10|| currentRow.getRowNum()==11) {
                continue;
            }

            //removing the last three rows containing total
            if (currentRow.getLastCellNum() < 0 || currentRow.getCell(startCell) == null || "".equals(currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringCellValue()) || (currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringCellValue() != null && currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringCellValue().contains("Total"))) {
                continue;
           }

            else {
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);


            if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                row.append(cellValue);
            }


            //adjusting the cell values with the | or BLANK 
            if(currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                row.append("");
            }else {
            row.append(SEPARATOR);
             }
            }
        }

        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: i don't understand what you want to achieve. can you clarify it?

Comment: I wan tto make the header as Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6loc,Name6admin,Name7loc,Name7admin..

Comment: are those 4 cells in the range or is it just name6? so is loc and admin a part of the range?

Comment: Do you mean loop by range if so then no, they are just name , i had nother name i just changed them

Comment: as i understand it, the header row consits of 1 or more merged cells. my question is, is only the upper row (the names) in the merged cells, or also the lower row (loc/admin)?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer only the Name6 and Name7 has merged cell

Comment: [this tells you how to remove merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045517/how-to-unmerge-cells-in-a-spreadsheet-using-apache-poi-java-library)

Comment: I don't want to remove merged cells i just want to swap up the below text to the up as I said

Comment: and to achieve that, you will have to split the merged cells into 2 separate cells

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but how i will swap up the below cells ??

Comment: read the values below, write them into the cell above and remove the line

Comment: @XtremeBaumer can you please edit my code?? it will be very helpful

Comment: Can anyone help ?? I am not really able to make it out